# Bypass GPG signature checks only for a single repository

Tags: apt, repository

I have read the following article: [How do I bypass/ignore the gpg signature checks of apt?](https://askubuntu.com/q/74345)

It outlines how to configure `apt` to not check the signatures of packages **at all**.

However, I'd like to *limit* the effect of this setting to a single (in this case locally hosted) repository.

That is: **all** official repositories should use the GPG signature check as usual, **except** for **the local repo**.

How would I go about doing that?

Failing that, what would be the advantage (security-wise) of signing the packages during an automated build (some meta-packages and a few programs) and then doing all that [secure `apt`](https://wiki.debian.org/SecureApt) prescribes? After all the host with the repo would then also be the one on which the secret GPG key resides.

Comment: In my opinion automated signing using an online key, while far from ideal, would be strictly better than not signing at all. It would also be much easier to set up (no need to configure each client to waive the checks) and much easier to transition to a better setup later should you want to.

Comment: @Celada: is that an opinion (that it's "strictly better") or is there a rationale for your statement? I'm asking, because so far I cannot see a reason how this would improve security or any other aspect. The only time when this would be somewhat beneficial, would be if I ever intended to publish my repo after all, no?

Comment: I hold that opinion rationally :-) If the repository is signed, then at least the bad guys have to get the signing key, which you will probably keep in only one place and probably on a dev box, or at least not readable by the HTTP server. Otherwise there is no protection at all. In other words I just mean to say that there is no disadvantage to signing, so you might as well sign even if the advantage is only tiny. And since it would be easier to set up, that's what I would go with.

Comment: @Celada: this is a repository for local use only. Who would be able to access it. Use case: a host with guest containers. Both host and containers will have access. No public access planned. But I guess I'll hold out for an answer a bit longer and go for the otherwise inevitable (signing).

Comment: Fair enough, we'll see if someone knows the answer to your question. I don't know what tool you're planning to use to generate the repo, but I recommend [reprepro](https://mirrorer.alioth.debian.org/). A lot of the other tools like `dput` (or whatever Debian itself uses) are very elaborate and seem like huge overkill for local-only ad hoc repo. `reprepro` will take care of generating the repo with all the correct directory layout and index files automatically without needing a big database server installation... and it will also sign the result with basically no additional work on your part.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You can set options in your `sources.list`:

```
deb [trusted=yes] http://localmachine/debian wheezy main
```

The `trusted` option is what turns off the GPG check. See `man 5 sources.list` for details.

Note: this was added in apt 0.8.16~exp3. So it's in wheezy (and of course jessie), but not squeeze.

Comment: This is definitely the best answer if you repeatedly need to access an unsigned repository, there are updated answers to the other question linked in the original question here showing how to temporarily do it per repository.

Answer (score 29):

To make sure that you see a warning while using an insecure repository, better use allow-insecure=yes instead like below

```
deb [ allow-insecure=yes ] ...
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks for your answer. A small but important difference indeed.