# Debian, apt-get: how do I ignore NO_PUBKEY for good?

Tags: debian, apt, qemu, powerpc

I have a qemu in which I have `debian-10.0-powerpc-NETINST-1` plus `sid` as package source. I need `powerpc` to as a reference big endian architecture (maybe there's something easier?)

[image: NO_PUBKEY]

My problem is that trying to install packages end me up with NO_PUBKEY errors, which I can't fight: `apt install debian-archive-keyring` did not do anything about it and I can't install `gpg` since I can't install **anything** due to broken apt-get with obsolete database which gives 404 for most of files.

Please tell me any options to ignore `NO_PUBKEY` for good. Since it's a throwaway qemu I don't care in the slightest, just let me ignore the stuff and install packages.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and use code formatting instead.

Comment: @muru there's no way I can get this text out of `qemu`, at least one I know of. I even have to type in commands and URLs instead of pasting.

Comment: You can pipe the output to `pastebinit` or similar, or connect from your local system to the VM via SSH, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `[trusted=yes]` to sources.list as shown in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/198454/57502) did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You could bypass apt and download/install it manually.

```
wget http://ftp.ports.debian.org/debian-ports/pool/main/d/debian-archive-keyring/debian-archive-keyring_2019.1_all.deb
dpkg -i debian-archive-keyring_2019.1_all.deb
```

Comment: I was able to install `debian-archive-keyring`, but the error did not disappear. Maybe I could install gnupg by downloading a couple dozen packages, but it's clearly not worth the time.

Comment: If `debian-archive-keyring` doesn't have the signatures needed, then your other solution is a better alternative.

Comment: It seems what I really needed was `debian-ports-archive-keyring`